# PHP form not carrying variable to actioned page?

Tags: php, forms, get, action

i am trying to create a form to create an html page for craigslist. here is the form

```
            <html>
            <head>


            </head>
            <body>


            <form action="bodytest.php"  method="post">

            Year
            <input type="text" name = "Year">;
            Make
            <input type="text" name = "Make">;
            Model
            <input type="text" name = "Model">;

            <input type="submit" value="Proceed">

            </form>

            </body>
            </html>
```

then here is the snippet of code that i want to pull the info

```
            <tr>
            <?php
            $year = $_POST['Year'];
            ?>
            <td style=" margin:5px; width:100px;">  <?php echo $year ?>  </td>
```

for some reason it is not pulling the information to the field, what is going wrong?

Comment: your form is ok. so, it's either some mistype or other problem on your side, invisible from here. doublecheck your code. check also HTML source. Do you have PHP installed?

Comment: yeah it looks like an issue with my server... i have php installed and i use another form on it which works fine.

Comment: first of all make action empty and add <?php print_r($_POST) ?> to the file with form. and then run it. if you will have some further questions/feedback, add @Col to your comment or otherwise I won't be notified of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no case-sensitivity, try naming your input `year` (since the capital Y is lost) and retrieving the data from `$_POST["year"]`.  There could also be problems with register globals settings (etc), so try a `print_r($_POST);` to see what's in there.

Comment: print_r($_POST) didnt return anything. probably an issue with calling the php server? i know that i have to do $year = $_REQUEST['year'] normally. but  that didnt help either

Comment: Yeah, it almost sounds like PHP isn't executing on the second page (the form/method/naming are all fine assuming the second code snippit is on a page called `bodytest.php` which doesn't have an `exit;` or similar command above your code-fragment).  Could try a `<?php echo "hello world;?>` command to see if we have ignition?

Comment: nope php is not excuting, i threw it on the bodytest.php file and it didn't execute, but like i said, i have files in the same parent directory that do work.